# Unable to connect to dedicated GMOD server

Tags: hosting, garrys-mod

I have this GMOD server running on my pc and even with extensive research, I cannot seem to connect to it. I have tried connecting with my public IP and port 27015 but it says it isn't responding. The server console shows no error regarding the server and says it's running fine, VAC secured and all.

I don't really know what info you need to diagnose a problem like this so just ask if there is anything I can provide.

Comment: Have you tried connecting with your local IP? Many routers don't allow connecting to your own public IP from the same device.

Comment: Yeah so I did dome debugging and I can connect from my own router but anyone over the internet can't.

Comment: Did you do your NAT/port forwarding correctly ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qdUxw41
My fibre router is connected to eth1

Comment: What operating system are you using to host? Did you try adding firewall exceptions for specific ports for the hosting system?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and have added more than enough exceptions for the application to use the port.